# Quick doubt about adding a Feature to a Vector Layer

Tags: openlayers, features

If I clone a feature from a Vector Layer `A` and I add it to another Layer `B`, I assume this happens only in client side and it doesn't really affect my `B` Layer on server at all, am I right?

```
# Note: Syntax is CoffeeScript

clone = featureFromA.clone()

# This returns the Source of a layer by its name
layerBSource = @app.getMapLayerSource('LayerB')

layerBSource.addFeature(clone)
```

I guess this is a really stupid question, but I didn't find any information on the [API Docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#addFeature) about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are just adding the feature at client side.
To store the source you need to use an appropriate write function for your desired `ol.format`.

E.g.

- `ol.format.GeoJSON.writeFeaturesObject(features, opt_options)` ([API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#writeFeaturesObject))
- `ol.format.WFS.writeTransaction(inserts, updates, deletes, options)` ([API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.WFS.html#writeTransaction))